# how to stop matlab from rounding my values and keep them at same precision during calculations?

Tags: matlab, digital-filters

here are my IIR coefficients:

```
CoefIIR=[1.630078934734 1.267893338385 1.112390120011]
```

and here are the result given to me by matlab commands:

```
CoefIIR =

1.6301    1.2679    1.1124
```

How can I keep the precision for data storage and during calculations?

Comment: The precision is kept. It is just the display values. Type `format long` to change the displayed precision.

Comment: you are right. I cannot unfortunately make your answer as the right one

Comment: It's ok, no worries. I am glad I helped.

Comment: @GKH: please copy your comment into an answer, below -- it certainly *is* a good answer, and should be recognized as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The precision is kept. It is just the display values that are truncated.

Type `format long` to change the displayed precision.